# Compare size of file and size of byte array of that file

Tags: android, arrays, type-conversion, filesize

When we convert the file (say - image) 
To byteArray how can be approximately compared between them (image file and byteArray) ?

Is there also a way to ***first convert image file to byteArray and this byteArray has to be written in a text-file..
Again after this read these lines of byteArray from text-file and make byteArray and hence converted to image file......*** I'm beginner and just for knowledge purpose i want to know....

Comment: you can directly compare `bytearray`. just do something like `bytearray.length == anotherBA.length`

Comment: Ok.. Thank you. Please tell me about the rest part of this question.

Comment: `When we convert the file (say - image) To byteArray h...` One cannot convert a file to an array. But one can place the bytes of a file directly in a byte array. Any file.

Comment: How you would place a byte array in a text file is beyond my imagination. Unless it was a text file that you loaded.

Comment: As you @blackapps are saying place bytes of a file to a byte array then after reading that byte array we can place these byte array data into text-file too as #Blu answered. This is just relation of #blackapps comment and #Blu answers. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert your image to byte array like this.

```
  BufferedImage bImage = ImageIO.read(new File("sample.jpg"));
  ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
  ImageIO.write(bImage, "jpg", bos );
  byte [] data = bos.toByteArray();
```

Yes you can directly compare 2 byteArray.

Just do something like

```
if (bytearray1.length == bytearray2.length)
   //its same
```

Try this to write the ByteArray in text file

```
public void writeToFile(byte[] array) 
{ 
   try 
   { 
       String path = "/data/data/YOURFILE.txt"; //provide your path here
       File file = new File(path);
       if (!file.exists()) { //just to check if file is actually present
          file.createNewFile();
       }
       FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(path); 
       stream.write(array); 
   } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) 
   { 
      e1.printStackTrace(); 
   } 
}
```

Comment: I have emphasized the text i wanted to ask something more than that you have answered :\